# How do I run an instance of Elasticsearch from within a Flask python application?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I am trying create a server with an instance of Elasticsearch using the Flask python framework. I have the simple code below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from datetime import datetime
from pyelasticsearch import ElasticSearch

""" Insert some code here that creates/runs the Elasticsearch instance """

es = ElasticSearch('http://localhost:9200/')

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime(2010, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
    }

es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', doc=doc,id=1,overwrite_existing=True)


def create_app():
   app = Flask(__name__)
   Bootstrap(app)
   return app

mainApp = create_app()

@mainApp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp.run(debug=True)
```

However, I can only get the mainApp to connect to the Elasticsearch instance if I start it outside of my application (i.e. run it on localhost 9200). However, what I would like to have happen is that when I run app.py, both my Flask server and the Elasticsearch instance to which it is connected are created. How would I do this in python? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are trying to connect to an Elasticsesrch instance running on localhost. Are you sure the server is running?

Comment: Isn't Flask supposed to set up the server which elasticsearch can use?

Comment: [Elasticsearch is a completely separate service.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elasticsearch)

Comment: So when I create the instance of Elasticsearch am I also creating the server on which it will run? I think that I am missing something conceptual here.

Comment: Elasticsearch is a service similar to a database (e.g., MySQL) or a cache (e.g., Memcached). You can run it locally or on another host. Once you have it running somewhere your Flask app can connect to it.

Comment: Also, I'm thinking that I need pyelasticsearch or flask-elasticsearch to do some heavy lifting for me.

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don't get why my elasticsearch instance is not connecting to the localhost.

Comment: Do you now have an Elasticsearch instance running on localhost? You can't connect to it until you do.

Comment: Does the line "es = ElasticSearch('http://localhost:9200/')" not set up an instance running on localhost? I still get the same connection error.

Comment: That line *connects to* the instance, it does not create it. It's just like calling `psycopg2.connect` to connect to a Postgres database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64566/discussion-between-matt-hoover-and-dirn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run elasticsearch's service first 
`sudo service elasticsearch start`
 and then serve your app